# PHP create array where key and value is same

Tags: php, arrays, range

I am using the `range()` function to create an array. However, I want the `keys` to be the same as the `value`. This is ok when i do `range(0, 10)` as the index starts from `0`, however if i do `range(1, 11)`, the index will still start from `0`, so it ends up `0=>1` when i want it to be `1=>1`

How can I use `range()` to create an array where the `key` is the same as the `value`?

Comment: Why not just not use the key at all?

Comment: im using a library i cannot modify that requires this >.<

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create an array for a range of values with keys using php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227875/how-do-i-create-an-array-for-a-range-of-values-with-keys-using-php)

Answer (score 144, accepted):

How about [array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)?

```
$b = array_combine(range(1,10), range(1,10));
```

or (as suggested in comments):

```php
$b = array_combine($r = range(1, 10), $r)
```

Comment: how does range returns array values? When we echo range(1,10) it displays full content? confusing dude?

Comment: `array_combine($r = range(1, 10), $r)` avoid recall `range` in 2 times.

Answer (score 7):

Or you did it this way:

```
$b = array_slice(range(0,10), 1, NULL, TRUE);
```

Find the output here: http://codepad.org/gx9QH7ES

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box solution for this. You will have to create the array yourself, like so:

```
$temp = array();
foreach(range(1, 11) as $n) {
   $temp[$n] = $n;
}
```

But, more importantly, *why* do you need this? You can just use the value itself?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function createArray($start, $end){
  $arr = array();
  foreach(range($start, $end) as $number){
    $arr[$number] = $number;
  }
  return $arr;
}

print_r(createArray(1, 10));
?>
```

See output here: http://codepad.org/Z4lFSyMy

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$array = array();
foreach (range(1,11) as $r)
  $array[$r] = $r;

print_r($array);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to make this:

```
if (! function_exists('sequence_equal'))
{
    function sequence_equal($low, $hight, $step = 1)
    {
        return array_combine($range = range($low, $hight, $step), $range);
    }
}
```

Using:

```
print_r(sequence_equal(1, 10, 2));
```

Output:

```
array (
  1 => 1,
  3 => 3,
  5 => 5,
  7 => 7,
  9 => 9,
)
```

In PHP 5.5 >= you can use Generator to make this:

```
function sequence_equal($low, $hight, $step = 1)
{
    for ($i = $low; $i < $hight; $i += $step) {

        yield $i => $i;
    }
}
```