# How do I create an array for a range of values with keys using php?

Tags: php, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

I am using CodeIgniter. I want to create an array to add to a dropdown which contains the numbers 1 -> 1000.

I have tried the php `range()` function like so

```
$arr = range(1,1000);
```

It worked and create a dropdown from 1 to 1000.

---

I do have one problem though.

When select text `1` from my drop down and post, the posting value is `0`.
Because by default the keys are starting from `0` and the key is set to the dropdown value

Here is part of my drop down HTML

```
<select id="user-day" class="dropdown-small Verdana11-424039" tabindex="123456" name="days_of_month">
<option value="0">1</option>
<option value="1">2</option>
<option value="2">3</option>
<option value="3">4</option>
<option value="4">5</option>
<option value="5">6</option>
<option value="6">7</option>
```

Is there any way I can define `range()` with key values?

Such that the values will become

```
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will form your array correctly using [array_combine](http://php.net/array_combine):

```
$array = array_combine( range(1,1000), range(1,1000));
```

Answer (score 4):

You could create an array the same way you're doing it, just expand the range a bit then unset the 0th element.

```
$arr = range(0,1000);
unset($arr[0]);
```

Comment: this will destroy first array, so instead 1000 list option you will get only 999

Comment: Yes it will destroy the 0th element of the array, but `range(0,1000)` is inclusive - there would be 1001 elements to the array it generates, therefore unsetting the 0th element would leave you with 1000 elements, 1-1000.

Comment: but if the range starting with 50, then will be wrong.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Umm, yes, this answer would be wrong then, as what you're saying is not the original problem.  Nice 4+ year necro comment, btw.

Answer (score 1):

Could use an old-fashioned for loop;

```
for ($i=1; $i <= 1000; $i++) {
   $arr[$i] = $i; 
}
print_r($arr);
```

Or just adjust the form population

```
$arr = range(1,10);
print_r($arr);
echo '<select>';
foreach ($arr as $a) {
   $value = $a+1;
   echo '<option value=\"'.$value.'">'.$a.'</option><br />';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create the array through a loop:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 1000; $i++)
    $arr[$i] = $i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use `value` attribute at all.
So, the form will send you option instead.

Answer (score -2):

Use the following code

```
<select id="user-day" class="dropdown-small Verdana11-424039" tabindex="123456" name="days_of_month">
<?php for ($i=0; $i <= 1000; $i++) { ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
<? } ?>
```